# Cannot use edge color to plot an igraph

Tags: igraph

I have the following graph:

```
gg <- 
structure(list(13, FALSE, 12, 8, 0, 0, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    list(na = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Species = c("Cutibacterium", 
    "Staphylococcus", "Streptococcus", "Enhydrobacter", "Corynebacterium", 
    "Lawsonella", "Rothia", "Neisseria", "Prevotella", "Anaerococcus", 
    "Haemophilus", "Snodgrassella", "Veillonella"), vertex.names = c("Cutibacterium", 
    "Staphylococcus", "Streptococcus", "Enhydrobacter", "Corynebacterium", 
    "Lawsonella", "Rothia", "Neisseria", "Prevotella", "Anaerococcus", 
    "Haemophilus", "Snodgrassella", "Veillonella")), list(color = "blue", 
        na = FALSE, weight = 9.95))), class = "igraph")



> gg
IGRAPH 07ee929 U-W- 13 1 -- 
+ attr: na (v/l), Species (v/c), vertex.names (v/c), color (e/c), na (e/l), weight (e/n)
+ edge from 07ee929:
[1] 9--13
```

I try to plot the graph as follows:

```
ggnet2(gg,edge.color="color",label="weight")
Error in ggnet2(gg3, edge.color = "color", edge.label = "weight") : 
  incorrect edge.color value
```

The color is properly assigned. There is only one edge.

```
 E(gg)$color
    [1] "green"
```

What am do doing wrong ?
Thanks,
david

Comment: am i wrong or is there something wrong in your gg igraph object? By copying and pasting an error is returned

Comment: I have removed the <environment> that was ouput by the dput command and was causing an error in the object. You can use it now.